# Django runtime migrations

Tags: django, migration

Could someone help me, give me an example or a link I didn't find yet, to create migrations at runtime, or in other words to use migrations to let users to add custom fields ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not a thing you should do.

Comment: As I didn't get apps like django-eav or django-mutant to work, and maybe because these kind of apps are not maintained for years, I thought this was the good way.
Could you give my kind of tip to handle this nicely and simply ? (I'm quite new to python/django)